# Prove that $\sqrt {2a+{\frac {36-8a}{a+9}}+2\sqrt {{a}^{2}+3}}+\sqrt {{ \frac {36-8a}{a+9}}}\leqslant 3+\sqrt{3}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $0\leqslant a \leqslant 3.$ Prove that:
$$f(a)=\sqrt {2a+{\frac {36-8a}{a+9}}+2\sqrt {{a}^{2}+3}}+\sqrt {{
\frac {36-8a}{a+9}}}\leqslant 3+\sqrt{3}$$

> The text for LHS:  sqrt(2*a+(36-8*a)/(a+9)+2*sqrt(a^2+3))+sqrt((36-8*a)/(a+9))

I found that the equality holds when $a=3$ or $a=1.$ I also found that when $3\ge a\ge 1$ then $f'(a)\ge 0$ but I can not prove it and I don't know what to do in the opposite case. Helps me!

Comment: looks very complicated, Is there any motivation for proving this or is it just some random inequality

Comment: Here is the derivative: $$f'(a) = \frac{a^2\sqrt{a^2+3}+18a\sqrt{a^2+3}+27\sqrt{a^2+3}+a^3+18a^2+81a}{\left(a+9\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{a^2+3}\sqrt{2a^2+10a+2a\sqrt{a^2+3}+18\sqrt{a^2+3}+36}}-\frac{27}{\sqrt{-2a+9}\left(a+9\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: What is your reason to put the `complex-analysis` tag?

Comment: If a computer is allowed, with the substitution $\frac {36-8a}{a+9} = x^2$ for $1\le x \le 2$, then square, after that, square again to remove the root sign.

Comment: @RiverLi Yeah! That's one solution, but I think it's very ugly.

Comment: @tthnew Yes, it is not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi This inequality is the result when I try to prove https://t-t-h-n-e-w.blogspot.com/2021/02/1721.html

Comment: @tthnew It is interesting.

Comment: @RiverLi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028695/prove-that-sqrtab-sqrtbc-sqrtca-leq-3-sqrt3/4028697#4028697 I posted it now, can you found another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the extrema of function $$f(a)=\sqrt {2a+{\frac {36-8a}{a+9}}+2\sqrt {{a}^{2}+3}}+\sqrt {{ \frac {36-8a}{a+9}}}$$ Its ugly first derivative is almost $0$ very close to $a=1$
$$f'(1)=\frac{12}{5 \sqrt{55}}-\frac{27}{10 \sqrt{70}}\sim  0.000904209$$ Similarly
$$f''(1)=\frac{4161}{4400 \sqrt{55}}+\frac{27}{1400 \sqrt{70}}\sim 0.129821 >0$$ confirms that it is a minimum. We also have
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{5} \left(2 \sqrt{55}+\sqrt{70}\right)\sim  4.63980$$

Now, you "just" need to prove that, in the range, $f'(a)$ does not cancel a second time.

**Edit**

If we make a series expansion around $a=1$, the minimum is
$$a_{min} \sim \frac{27 \left(5687 \sqrt{14}-3871 \sqrt{11}\right)}{67963 \sqrt{11}+1089 \sqrt{14}}\approx 0.993035$$
$$f(a_{min} )\approx 4.639796308297$$ while a full optimization gives
$$a_{min}\approx 0.993066 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(a_{min} )\approx 4.639796308235$$

In the same spirit, we could show that the first derivative goes though a maximum close to $a=2$ (exactly at $a\approx 2.06292$) and an expansion around $a=2$ shows that it would cancel again around $a\approx 3.23940 >3$ (the exact value would be $a\approx3.24253$).

Comment: But $4.63980$ is $\neq 3+\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @tthnew: $4.63980 \lt 3+\sqrt{3}$