# Prove that $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\leq 3+\sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, symmetric-polynomials

**Problem.** (Nguyễn Quốc Hưng) Let $0\le a,b,c\le 3;ab+bc+ca=3.$ Prove that $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\leq 3+\sqrt{3}$$
I have one solution but ugly, so I 'd like to find another. I will post my solution in the answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\leq 1 + \sqrt k + \sqrt{k+1}$ works for $k \geq 2$ (not sure for $k=1$, probably it does) given $0 \leq a, b, c \leq k; ab + bc + ca = k$.

Comment: Hey downvote-er, why you do that? Don't downvote someone just because you don't like the inequality.

Comment: @MathLover I have just checked it. It's also true for $k=1.$

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Solution.}$ (*Khang Nguyen*) We have $$(3-a)(3-b)(3-c)\ge 0 \rightarrow abc+9(a+b+c)\le 36$$
Assume that $$(b-1)(c-1)\ge 0 \rightarrow 36\ge 8a+(9+a)(b+c)\Rightarrow b+c\le \dfrac{(36-8a)}{9+a}$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS}&=\sqrt{2a+b+c+2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}+\sqrt{b+c}\\&
\le \sqrt{2a+\dfrac{36-8a}{9+a}+2\sqrt{a^2+3}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{36-8a}{9+a}}\\&\le 3+\sqrt{3}.
\end{align*}
Let $\dfrac{36-8a}{9+a}=x^2\, \left(1\le x\le 2\right),$ after simplify it becomes:
$$ \left( {x}^{2}+8 \right)  \left( \sqrt {3}+3-x \right) \ge \sqrt {{x}^{2
 }+8}\sqrt {{x}^{4}+4\sqrt {3}\sqrt {7{x}^{4}-50{x}^{2}+124}-10
 {x}^{2}+72}$$
Or $$\sqrt{x^2+8} \left( \sqrt {3}+3-x \right) \ge \sqrt {{x}^{4}+4\sqrt {3}\sqrt {7{x}^{4}-50{x}^{2}+124}-10
 {x}^{2}+72}$$
Since $x\le 2\rightarrow \sqrt{3}+3-x\ge \sqrt{3}+3-2>0\rightarrow \text{VT}>0.$ By squaring both sides, we need to prove
$$-2 \left( \sqrt {3}+3 \right)  \left( \sqrt {3}{x}^{2}+{x}^{3}-6{x
}^{2}-10\,\sqrt {3}+8\,x+6 \right) \ge 4\sqrt {3}\sqrt {7\,{x}^{4}-50\,
{x}^{2}+124}$$
It's easy to prove $\text{LHS}>0$ and from here the inequality is equivalent to
$$24\left( 2+\sqrt {3} \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+8 \right)  \left( 2
\sqrt {3}x+{x}^{2}+8\sqrt {3}-9x-10 \right)  \left( x-2 \right) 
\left( x-1 \right) \ge 0,$$
One more time, we can check that this inequality is true for all $1 \le x \le 2$ and done!

Equality holds when $(a,b,c)=(3,1,0)$ and permutations.

See also [here](https://t-t-h-n-e-w.blogspot.com/2021/02/1721.html).

Comment: Nice solution thnew,In my opinion  its not so ugly,+1

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts**:

WLOG, assume $a\ge b \ge c$.

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sqrt{a+b} + \sqrt{b + c} + \sqrt{c + a} 
\le \sqrt{ \left( \frac{a + b}{2} + (b+c) + \frac{c+a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)(2 + 1 + \sqrt{3})}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{a + b}{2} + (b+c) + \frac{c+a}{\sqrt{3}} \le 3 + \sqrt{3}.$$
This is true. Is there nice solutions?

Comment: Nice idears, thanks, I really hope for that last ineq. (+1)

Comment: What style, sir

Comment: Let x = $(a, b, c)^T$, the problem can now be formulated as maximizing $c^Tx$ given $x^TMx$

Comment: @khanh Actually, there is additional constraint $0\le a, b, c \le 3$ and $a\ge b \ge c$, so it may not admit an easy solution.